# Getting node.js and Django on same domain

Tags: django, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

For a brief overview/desciption, I am using Django as the bread and butter for a webapp.  I want to add a bunch of "real-time" features to the app.  More so then I can do with stuff like Torndao or django-socketio.  So what I would like to do is take the full dive and use Django with node.js.  Basically, Django will get all the data and and handle all the accounts.  Then when a piece of data changes, it will send a message using AMQP which will route the message to node.js.  Node.js will then use socket.io to get the fresh data to the browser.

My question is how to get the two to play together.  Specifically, how can I get both on the same domain so that when the client connects to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://thedomain.com');
```

it will be dealt with by node.js and all the other requests will go to Django?  Also, I would ideally like to have the Django app running on Heroku as a standalone app and have the node.js also running on Heorku on the standalone app, if possible.  Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!